# value stored as array in the database getting deleted while adding new values into the same array while updating

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, array-push

Here my problem is when i go for updating the values already stored in the database is getting deleted and only the newly added values are getting
here is my code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if(destId=='bar3' || sourceId=='bar3') {
            var itemvalue2 =Array();
            $('ul#bar3 li').each(function() {
                itemvalue2.push($(this).attr("value"));
            });
            document.getElementById("bar3-output").value=itemvalue2;
        }
    });
</script>
```

here is my view

```
<ul id="bar3"  class="block__list block__list_tags">
    <input type="hidden" id="bar3-output" name="all_active_menu3" class="form-control" 
    value="<?php if(!empty($team_info->members)) {
        $tagsArray = explode(',', $team_info->members);
        $tagsLinksArray = array();
        foreach($tagsArray as $tag) {
            $tagName = trim($tag);
            $tagsLinksArray[]=$tagName;
        }
        $tagsLinks = implode(',', $tagsLinksArray);
        echo $tagsLinks;}?>
    ">
</ul>
```

Here is my control

```
public function save_team($team_id = NULL)
{
    $profile_data=$this->Teams_model->array_from_post(array('team_name'));
    $this->Teams_model->_table_name = 'tbl_teams'; // table name
    $this->Teams_model->_primary_key = 'team_id'; // $id
    if (!empty($team_id)) {
        $profile_data['members']=$this->input->post('all_active_menu3');
        $this->Teams_model->save($profile_data, $team_id);
    } else {
        $profile_data['members']=$this->input->post('all_active_menu3');
        $this->Teams_model->save($profile_data);
    }

    if (!empty($team_id)) {
        $message = ('Team Info Updated');
    } else {
        $message = ('Team Info Saved');
    }
    $type = 'success';
    set_message($type, $message);
    redirect('admin/team/team_list'); //redirect page
}
```

the value in the database is not becoming stable i had used many ideas but didn't reached destination.hope your help please help me

Comment: In both cases you're doing a straight assignment which would replace the data for the members entirely with whatever is selected from `all_active_menu3`. Rather than a straight assignment your probably would need to add those values to that array.

Comment: yaa i got it but how i dont know

Comment: i want the first value inserted to be remain

Comment: Using more descriptive names for your stuff would certainly help understanding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain how your code works but here is what my guess is and what is going wrong: You're just replacing the old value in both cases.

This seems to be the relevant code fragment.

```
$profile_data=$this->Teams_model->array_from_post(array('team_name'));
//...
if (!empty($team_id)) {
    $profile_data['members']=$this->input->post('all_active_menu3');
    $this->Teams_model->save($profile_data, $team_id);
} else {
    $profile_data['members']=$this->input->post('all_active_menu3');
    $this->Teams_model->save($profile_data);
}
```

The first assignment of `$profile_data` reads the current team data from the existing team. Your naming is a bit confusing as you're not actually reading any POST data it seems. The assignment within the if block that would fulfill the condition `!empty($team_id)` should update the team members and the false block should create a new team. Did you verify that `$team_id` gets set successfully?

I'm not certain about the structure of the team information but rather than a straight assignment using `=` in the true block you should be using `+=` or manually combine the new and old data and do the assignment afterwards.

Using something like [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) or a loop to create an intermittent object to hold the combined data should work here.

Comment: i had used array_merge function but didn't got..yaa $team_id gets set successfully

Comment: What do you mean it didn't go? How did you use it? What is the actual structure read from the DB and the structure you get from `$this->input->post('all_active_menu3')`?

Comment: Nice. Did this help? If so, consider marking it as an answer. if it didn't consider adding an answer yourself and mark it as an answer with the solution so someone who runs into a similar issue might get an idea. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)